# Is it possible to keep the different color palettes of two lineplots on the same axes in a manually changed legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two lineplots plotted on the same axes. Each plot represents a different group and consists of two lines representing one of two conditions. Additonally each group is given a different colour palette (*Blues* for Group 1 and *Reds* for Group 2).

The automatically created legend keeps track of the colour palette defined for each plot but misses the information about the group.

How can I manually change the legend while keeping the colours of both plots the same.

Or is there even another method to include the group dimension to the legend in matplotlib?

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'block': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        'cond': ['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2'],
        'value': [1, 2, 1.2, 2.1, 1.1, 2.2, 3, 4, 3.3, 4.1, 3.1, 4]}
```

Output:

```
      group  block cond  value
0       1      1   c1    1.0
1       1      1   c2    2.0
2       1      2   c1    1.2
3       1      2   c2    2.1
4       1      3   c1    1.1
5       1      3   c2    2.2
6       2      1   c1    3.0
7       2      1   c2    4.0
8       2      2   c1    3.3
9       2      2   c2    4.1
10      2      3   c1    3.1
11      2      3   c2    4.0
```

```
sns.lineplot(data=df.loc[df['group'] == 1], x='block', y='value', hue='cond',
             palette='Blues', marker='o')

sns.lineplot(data=df.loc[df['group'] == 2], x='block', y='value', hue='cond',
             palette='Reds', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

This  is what I get if I normally plot both lines in a graph

[image: This is what I get if i normally plot both lines in a graph]

If i now try to manually rename the conditions in the legend by adding the group the lines belong to using the following line:

```
plt.legend(title='Legend', labels=['Group 1: C1', 'Group 1: C2', 'Group 2: C1', 'Group 2: C2'])
```

The colour information of one of the plots is getting lost in the legend

[image: This is what happens]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the legend handles from the lineplot plots as well before you set the legend and modify the text. Please see if the updated code is what you are looking for... Hope this helps.

```
data = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'block': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        'cond': ['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2'],
        'value': [1, 2, 1.2, 2.1, 1.1, 2.2, 3, 4, 3.3, 4.1, 3.1, 4]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
sns.lineplot(data=df.loc[df['group'] == 1], x='block', y='value', hue='cond',
             palette='Blues', marker='o')
sns.lineplot(data=df.loc[df['group'] == 2], x='block', y='value', hue='cond',
             palette='Reds', marker='o')

## Get the legend handles and add them to plt.legend, so that the right handles are addigned
legend_handles, _= plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles = legend_handles, title='Legend', loc='right',
           labels=['Group 1: C1', 'Group 1: C2', 'Group 2: C1', 'Group 2: C2'])
plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn's recommended way to change the names of the legend entries, is to (temporarily) rename the values in the hue column.

To get the marker in the legend, you can use `style=` with the hue column, set `dashed=False`, and `markers=['o']*len(hues)`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = {'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'block': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        'cond': ['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c2'],
        'value': [1, 2, 1.2, 2.1, 1.1, 2.2, 3, 4, 3.3, 4.1, 3.1, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
hues = df['cond'].unique()
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df[df['group'] == 1].replace({'cond': {c: 'Group 1: ' + c for c in hues}}),
                  x='block', y='value', hue='cond',
                  palette='Blues', style='cond', dashes=False, markers=['o'] * len(hues))
sns.lineplot(data=df[df['group'] == 2].replace({'cond': {c: 'Group 2: ' + c for c in hues}}),
             x='block', y='value', hue='cond',
             palette='Reds', style='cond', dashes=False, markers=['o'] * len(hues), ax=ax)
sns.move_legend(ax, title='Legend', loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.02), frameon=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lineplot with combined legend]

PS: To make the code easier to modify later, you can write the calls to `sns.lineplot` in a loop:

```py
hues = df['cond'].unique()
for group, pal in zip(df['group'].unique(), ['Blues', 'Reds']):
    sns.lineplot(data=df[df['group'] == group].replace({'cond': {c: f'Group {group}: {c.upper()}' for c in hues}}),
                 x='block', y='value', hue='cond',
                 palette=pal, style='cond', dashes=False, markers=['o'] * len(hues))
```